Getting filename from clipboard in R
In R, is it possible to get the full path and filename (in Windows) of a file copied to clipboard?
Background is that I have several large Excel files containing data I'd like to process in R.
The filesystem is relatively unstructured, so getting the paths/filenames of these files programatically is not really an option. I don't want to open the Excel files for copy-pasting data into R either, because opening large Excels takes a lot of time. So I am looking for an option where I can navigate to a file using the file explorer, copy the file to clipboard, and then reading in the content of the file into R, which I could set up if I can extract file name and path.
Both utils::readClipboard() and clipr::read_clip() return NULL if a file is copied to clipboard.

You can use file.choose() to select a file using the system dialogs.

I don’t currently have access to Windows but have a look at the value of getClipboardFormats(), it might give you an indication of how Windows stores file paths in the clipboard, and have a look at the documentation.

Try format = 15L. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156638/1968. You may also need to specify raw = TRUE and parse the raw data into a string.

Aside from Konrad Rudolph's neat solution: many editors offer sequential file path auto-completion (usually through hitting TAB) and a file explorer. That way you don't have to switch between your editor and other applications.

Expanding upon Konrad's comments, you can get the file path from a file copied to the clipboard using readClipboard() with formats 49158 (short filename) and 49159 (long filename).  As an example, after copying the R executable to the clipboard:
# Short filename
readClipboard(format = "49158", raw = TRUE) |> 
  rawToChar()
    
[1] "C:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-44~1.1\\bin\\x64\\R.exe"

# Long filename
readClipboard(format = "49159", raw = TRUE) |> 
    rawToChar(multiple = TRUE) |> 
    paste0(collapse = "")

[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.4.1\\bin\\x64\\R.exe"


Thanks a lot! For me, format = 15L did not work, instead I needed to put format = 49158, which was also mentioned in this post.
The reason was presumably because the files are not on my computer, but on my companies network drives. Following Konrad's first comment, you can use getClipboardFormats() to identify candidate values for format.

utils Package covers this
Read the clipboard content
file_path <- utils::readClipboard()

Print the file path
print(file_path)

many interesting option to play about here have fun :)
https://rdrr.io/r/utils/clipboard.html

OP already tried that, unsuccessfully.
